# Instantiate different classes depending on option in menu

Tags: c#, class, oop, instantiation

I'm working on a "simple" game for fun kinda like Factorio, but not grid-based.
Now I need some kind of system to keep track of all my different building-types and to let the player pick a type in a menu. The menu is handled by the `UI` class and that class calls methods in the `Game` class to check against money and whatnot. The `Game` class then calls the `World` class to add whatever building the player selected. At least that's the relevant bit, I think.

As I have it now, to store the different building-types I have a class named `BuildInstruction` with sub-classes `BuildingBuildInstruction` and `ConnectionBuildInstruction`. These classes simply holds Action<> thingamabobs that returns a building / connection when given world-coordinate / two connection-points.

I've run in to some problems with this method though both in the `Game`- and `IU`-class. I can't seem to divide the work between the classes in a logical fashion...

I know this is a ridiculously vague question but it's kinda hard for me to formulate. Basically, it would be awesome if someone knew of some sort of common practice for these sorts of things... I'm open to all suggestions.

Thank you!

And BTW, here's some code if it helps to understand:

This is what I use to pass options in a sort of hierarchy to the menu:

```
public class Category<T>
{
    public string Label { get; private set; }

    public T Me { get; private set; }

    List<Category<T>> children = new List<Category<T>>();

    public IEnumerable<Category<T>> Children => children;

    public bool HasChildren => children.Count() > 0;

    public Category(string label, List<Category<T>> _children)
    {
        Label = label;
        children = _children;
    }

    public Category(string label, T me)
    {
        Label = label;
        Me = me;
    }
}
```

This is the `BuildInstruction` class with sub-classes and the static List<> of `BuildInstruction` objects that I then give to the menu.

```
public abstract class BuildInstruction
{
    public static Category<BuildInstruction> BuildInstructions;

    static BuildInstruction()
    {
        BuildInstructions = new Category<BuildInstruction>("Build", new List<Category<BuildInstruction>>()
        {
            new Category<BuildInstruction>("Powergrid", new List<Category<BuildInstruction>>()
            {
                new Category<BuildInstruction>("Powerline", new ConnectionBuildInstruction(
                    (start, end) =>
                    new Powerline(start as IPowerlineConnectable, end as IPowerlineConnectable)
                ))
            }),
            new Category<BuildInstruction>("Logistics", new List<Category<BuildInstruction>>()
            {
                new Category<BuildInstruction>("Pipeline", new ConnectionBuildInstruction(
                    (start, end) =>
                    new Pipeline(start as IPipelineConnectable, end as IPipelineConnectable)
                )),
                new Category<BuildInstruction>("Stockpile", new BuildingBuildInstruction(
                    (worldPos) =>
                    new Stockpile(worldPos)
                ))
            })
        });
    }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public class BuildingBuildInstruction : BuildInstruction
{
    Func<PointF, Building> BuildFunction;

    public BuildingBuildInstruction(Func<PointF, Building> buildFunction)
    {
        BuildFunction = buildFunction;

    }

    public Building Build(PointF worldPos)
    {
        return BuildFunction(worldPos);
    }
}

public class ConnectionBuildInstruction : BuildInstruction
{
    Func<IConnectable, IConnectable, Connection> BuildFunction;

    public ConnectionBuildInstruction(Func<IConnectable, IConnectable, Connection> buildFunction)
    {
        BuildFunction = buildFunction;
    }

    public Connection Build(IConnectable start, IConnectable end)
    {
        return BuildFunction(start, end);
    }
}
```

And finally, the Game class:

```
public class Game
{
    World World = new World();

    public Game()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        World.Draw(g);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------

    public void BuyBuilding(Building building)
    {
        if (true) //Check money and whatnot...
        {
            if (ConstructBuilding(building))
            {
                //Success, use money and stuff
            }
            else
            {
                //Fail. Feedback!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Not enough money or whatnot. Feedback!
        }
    }

    bool ConstructBuilding(Building building)
    {
        return World.AddWorldObject(new ConstructionSite(building));
        //This ConstructionSite class is just a thing that makes it so that 
        //the actual building-process takes some time in-game
    }
}
```

I think the `UI` class would just be confusing and too much code (already to much?) but it just calls the `BuyBuilding()` method in `Game`. For now, I have the `BuyBuilding()` method take a `Building` object, but I don't really know if that's a good way to do it...

PS.
If this is too vague and too ridiculous, then don't hesitate to delete it, I'm just trying to see if maybe someone somewhere has any suggestions or thoughts...

Thank you again! :D

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the question, but maybe take a look at the Abstract Factory design pattern.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks for the early reply, I'll check it out! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this

one option would be a Build Class

```
public class BuildBuilding
{
    public Point Location{get;set;}
    public BuildingType Type{get;set;}

    public void Create(){
        ///logic for creation here
    }
}
```

this would let you wire up INotifyPropertyChanged or some other monitoring function, your UI could then be used to set the properties of the class, say mouse to location and menu to type

if you don't need that level of complexity a simple static creator function could work this is what you have tried

```
public abstract class BuildingType 
{

    public static Building Create(Point location, BuildingType type){
        ///logic for creation here
    }
}
```

here the UI would have to feed all parameters in at once but as long as you don't have anything too complex it is doable

or you could define and interface or virtual function that will do the work in the child class

```
public abstract class BuildingType 
{
    public abstract Building Create(Point location);//logic in child
}

public interface IBuildable
{
    void Create(Point location)
}
```

either of these will enforce an abstract handle you can use to define a method handle with out behaviour here you could wire your UI up to each type and then call the common function on activation